# Saving the response cache to the server in Net 5

Tags: caching, asp.net-core-mvc, http-caching, httpresponsecache, responsecache

As in Net MVC, I want to save the response cache to the server (it's called outputcache), but there is no such feature in Net Core or Net 5. I couldn't find an alternative method. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Blackerback, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to learn Response caching in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Hello @Rena, I have reviewed this and many documents many times, but when I press the F5 key, all cache data is deleted, I need to use server side cache structure to prevent it from being deleted (OutputCache Location.Server etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WebEssentials.AspNetCore.OutputCaching](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.OutputCaching/) nuget to achieve your requirement.

Follow the steps below:

1.Add the middleware:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
         services.AddOutputCaching();
         //other middleware...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseOutputCaching();

        //other middleware...
    }
}
```

2.Add `OutputCache` attribute to the action:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 600)]
public IActionResult Index()
{ ... }
```

---

A sample code for testing:

Controller:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 600)]
public IActionResult Index()
{        
    return View(DateTime.Now);
}
```

View:

```
@model DateTime

Time of request: @Model.ToString()
```

Try requesting the page and notice that the date and time remains the same, even when reloading the page, until the cache has expired.

OutputCache contains not least `Duration` option, but also other options, such as `VaryByHeader`, `VaryByParam` and so on...

More details you can refer to the [github repo for WebEssentials.AspNetCore.OutputCaching](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.OutputCaching)

Comment: Waiting for your response.

Comment: It works fine for me. I want to write a middleware about it, that it will cache or not according to the incoming route value. How can I use this?

Comment: I suggest you can use MapWhen middleware like below:https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU6H8.png. The detailed document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#branch-the-middleware-pipeline